# Rename multiple folders using shell script

Tags: shell

How do I rename multiple user defined folder/files?

Say for Ex. I have multiple folders like
krish,
moorthy,
ravi,
robert,
etc..

I want to rename all these directories as script_1 , script_2, script_3 etc. I tried below script but it doesn't produce an output:

```
for i in *
do
mv $* $script_'$i'
done
```

While executing, it says it cannot move, cannot stat *

Please help me to go through this.

Comment: style your code correctly, it won't let me edit it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash
s=1
for i in *
do
  mv  $i  "script_$s"
  s=$((s+1))
done
```

i in the loop represents the current file/directory; it's not an index, so you need a separate indexing variable, I called it s.

Answer (score 0):

```
j=1;
for i in $(ls); do
   mv $i script_$j && j=$[$j +1]; 
done
```

`for i in ...` returns the *value* as `i`, not the index. Here, I've just added a new variable `j` as the incrementing index.